# How to open another view when button is clicked in iOS app development?

Tags: swift4

I am trying to build an app, and I want another view to open up once I click a button. I have searched for an answer, but nothing came up. I already have the button done, but I don't know how to get another view to show up. The view should be another view within the app. I am just a beginner in xCode. Thanks.

I am currently using xCode 9, and swift 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this either using the storyboard or programmatically. Using the storyboard, you can ctrl-drag from the button to the other view controller and the segue will be wired up for you, like so:[image]

If you aren't using storyboards at all, you can use the .show method of the ViewController in the button action. [Apple has a good guide on segues.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question, consider accepting this as the answer